# Xtext: keywords as identifier

Tags: glsl, xtext

I have the following problem:
Im creating an editor for the GLSL Shading language. I would like to allow keywords as identifier on certain occasions, because the names of the builtin-functions can be used as identifiers.

for example: `vec3 texture=vec3(1,2,3);` is valid, even though `texture` is a builtin function.

this is the rule for the builtin functions:

```
BuiltInFunction:
'abs' |
'acos' |
'acosh' |
'all' |
'any' |
'asin' |
'asinh' |
'atan' |
'atanh' |
'atomicAdd' |
'atomicAnd' |
//etc...
```

this is the identifier terminal rule:

```
terminal IDENTIFIER: (('a'..'z')|('A'..'Z')|'_') (('a'..'z')|('A'..'Z')|'_'|('0'..'9'))*;
```

This is the result in the editor. `texture` and `abs` are not recognized as identifier.

[image]

the full grammar for reference: http://paste2.org/YwDNkBYW

**Solution:**

I created a source file with all the builtin functions:

```
common void abs(); 
common void acos(); 
common void acosh(); 
common void all(); 
common void any(); 
common void asin(); 
common void asinh(); 
common void atan(); 
common void atanh(); 
common void atomicAdd(); 
common void atomicAnd(); 
common void atomicCompSwap(); 
//etc...
```

i used the preserved keyword `common` to distinguish between builtin functions and locally created ones:

```
BuiltInFunctionDeclaration returns FunctionDeclaration:
    'common' qualifier=TypeQualifier? type=Type name=BuiltInFunction LEFT_PAREN (args+=Parameter (COMMA args+=Parameter)*)? RIGHT_PAREN (functionBlock=BlockStatement|SEMICOLON)
;

BuiltInFunction returns Function:
    ({BuiltInFunction}name=IDENTIFIER)
;

FunctionDeclaration:
    qualifier=TypeQualifier? type=Type name=Function LEFT_PAREN (args+=Parameter (COMMA args+=Parameter)*)? RIGHT_PAREN (functionBlock=BlockStatement|SEMICOLON)
;

Function:
    ({Function}name=IDENTIFIER)
;
```

...added these in the ScopeProvider:

```
public IScope scope_CallFunction_name(CallFunction context,EReference reference){
    ... add local functions to list ...
    if(builtInFunctions==null){
        ResourceSet set=file.eResource().getResourceSet();
        Resource r=set.createResource(URI.createURI("internal:/builtin.glsl"));
        try {
            //Internals.builtInFunctions is a String of the source file.
            r.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(Internals.builtInFunctions.getBytes()), set.getLoadOptions());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        builtInFunctions=((GLSLFile) r.getContents().get(0)).getFunctions().stream()
                .map(FunctionDeclaration::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    functions.addAll(builtInFunctions);
    return Scopes.scopeFor(functions);
}
```

and in the `ISemanticHighlightingCalculator` I added this check inside the iterator loop:

```
        if(current instanceof CallFunction){
            if(((CallFunction) current).getName() instanceof BuiltInFunction){
                acceptor.addPosition(node.getOffset(), node.getLength(), "CallBuiltInFunction");
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, can you also give us a full file example for your dsl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In xtext, keywords override IDENTIFIER rule. When you use IDENTIFIER in a rule it will never match a keyword.

If you want to do it anyway, you have to combine these rules into a new one:

```
keywordOrIdentifier:
    BuiltInFunction | IDENTIFIER
;
```

Then you have to use this rule instead of IDENTIFIER rule:

```
Function:
    {Function} name=keywordOrIdentifier
;
```

With this modification, your grammar will parse what you want, like in this example:

```
vec3 texture(float x, float y) {
    return vec(1,2,3)
}
```

The only problem with this solution is that the word texture will be colored as a keyword whereas in this context it's not a keyword. I think you can override this behavior with a custom *SemanticHighlighingCalculator*.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good idea, but unfortunately it wont work either. now there are so many alternatives for matching an identifier that the lexer dfa cant be created. the error is: `error(10):  internal error: org.antlr.tool.Grammar.createLookaheadDFA(Grammar.java:1279): could not even do k=1 for decision 4; reason: timed out (>1000ms)`
Maybe a better idea would be to treat builtin functioncalls as imported references. unfortunately i dont really know how to do that either :D

Comment: I tested my solution and it works, I only did these 2 modifications to your grammar (added keywordOrIdentifier and modified Function). Also I don't understand what you're calling "imported references".

Comment: well, that is weird because thats exaclty what i did. maybe i overlooked something... My problem is resolved anyway, because i managed to create another sourcefile, that contains dummy methods for all builtin functions. this file is loaded in the scopeprovider to be refered to by funcioncalls. This way i could even create a typeaware validator for these functions and add more functions if they are added in the next versions of glsl. this is what i meant with "imported references". thank you anyway for your help! ill edit my question and add the answer.